# JPA Specification complex query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have below data :-

```
Product Reason Qty
Pepsi   IN     10
Pepsi   Out    2
Pepsi   In     15
Pepsi   Out    5 
Coke    IN     100
Coke    Out    20
Coke    In     35
Coke    Out    25
```

and from JPA Specification i want to execute below query something like below :-

```
select * from (
(select SUM(QTY) from stock where reason like 'IN') as INDATA -
(select SUM(QTY) from stock where reason like 'OUT') as OUTDATA

) as TBL;
```

result will be below :-

```
Product Qty
Pepsi   18
Coke    90
```

I am using JPA Specification for the first time and i dont no idea how to execute the query to get current stock from stock table.

Comment: It's not clear how you get to 18 and 90, simplifying your sample data set further to maybe 3 rows for each cola company might make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an `Entity`, say `Beverage`, that is mapped to the above table `Stock` as :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Stock")
class Beverage {
    public Beverage(String brand, String reason, int quantity) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.reason = reason;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Beverage() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;

    String brand;
    String reason;
    int quantity;
}
```

You can use `case statement along with sum` as below with `JPQL`:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select new map(b.brand as brand, sum(case b.reason when 'IN' then b.quantity else -b.quantity end) as quantity)  from Beverage b group by b.brand");
List<Map> list = query.getResultList();
for(Map m : list)
    System.out.println(m.get("brand") + "-" + m.get("quantity"));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i am using some like this link. http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications 
and in my current method i am not able to find createQuery it has only three argument as 
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Stockdiary> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder)

Comment: Can you please give me idea how to do it with CriteriaBuilder.